# Multiple tabs with their own Ajax calls are preventing new tabs from loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have two different webpages the second of which is accessible through a link found on the first page. When the second page is done loading, a large AJAX request is initialized (Can take over 30 seconds for the response because the data is coming from a huge and slow database). While that ajax response is pending, if the user opens a new tab and enters the url of one of my two webpages, neither will load until after that 30 second ajax call from the original page is done loading.

This is problematic because the initial load time of the first page is (ignoring the ajax request) normally is instantaneous and now it is being drawn out to 30 seconds in the worst case scenario.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share some code of what you are doing?

Comment: I have same problem. I think this happen cause browser use one TCP connection and wait response on first request.